# Images not found after migrating Wordpress website

Tags: images, database, uploads, migration

I recently migrated my website to a new hosting platform and since uploading the files and changing the database details, some images aren't being found. I've checked the FTP and the files are in the correct folders.

I did find that this is only happening to images which have special characters in them such as the £ sign. For example, in the console it says this:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/what-will-%C2%A3500000-buy-where-you-live-bury-st-edmunds-%C2%A3475000.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Originally, I uploaded the images in Wordpress with £ signs and these are the files I transferred over when migrating.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/what-will-£500000-buy-where-you-live-bury-st-edmunds-£3475000.jpg
```

I have tried renaming the images, replacing the £ sign with %C2%A3 and uploading but they are still not being found. I have also tried regenerating all images on the site and flushing permalinks but still no luck.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reupload files via ftp, i believe you did via cpanel and filenames corrupted.
Also you can use plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/clean-image-filenames/